# C# Dynamic linq Contains method with parameter

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I tried to write **dynamic** linq like this:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string name;
    public List<string> list;
}

void sth()
{
    List<string> _aim = new List<string>();

    List<MyStruct> _source = new List<MyStruct>();

    _source.Where(it => _aim.Contains(it.name));
}
```

But I have problem with contains method with parameter. Anyone know how to do this in easy and generic way?
By function link that:

```
public static IQuerable<T> Sths(this IQuerable<T> source, IQuerable<string> aim, string columnName)
```

where name is in columnName, source is generic and aim is list of strings.

Comment: That should work as long as MyStruct.name is a string. What's the comtains method error saying?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @cahinton He doesn't have any implementation for his dynamic version at all.  He has a *static* version that works fine, but he doesn't know how to *dynamically* implement it.

Answer (score 0):

So to do this we can write up an expression that takes, as a parameter, the property's value, and uses it to perform the `Contains` check as an easy way of building that portion of the expression.  After that we can replace the parameter from that expression's body with an expression that accesses the property value from the parameter representing an item in the source, and then build up the lambda using that body.

```
public static IQueryable<T> ProjectionIsIn<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    IQueryable<string> collection,
    string columnName)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    Expression<Func<string, bool>> containsExpression =
        s => collection.Contains(s);

    var predicateBody = containsExpression.Body.Replace(
                containsExpression.Parameters[0],
                Expression.Property(param, columnName));
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicateBody, param);
    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

The following method is used to replace all instance of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine. 
But I found error in my application. 
I don't have parameter but member and this was problem.